# forward domain and remove subdirectories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Currently I am trying to forward our website to a subreddit while we our data to a new server.

Using htaccess I am using this:

```
Redirect 302 / http://reddit.com/r/myreddit
```

But if someone goes to `domain.com/forum` it'll redirect to the subreddit but also append forum to it, so it redirect to

`http://reddit.com/r/myredditforum`

which isn't what I want. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can your try `RedirectMatch` with regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^ http://reddit.com/r/myreddit
```

Aso test it in a different browser to avoid caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```